# How to take current input value and using it in the same view (C# MVC)?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, view

```html
<input type="text" id="investorinfo" name="investorinfo" />
<button type="submit" class="btn_1 medium">Search</button>
```

I am trying to take a string from the `<input>` and when the user presses the search button, I want to use the string as the `searchparameter` in the below code block.

I tried to use in JS but I have to pass it to a c# code block in a view but I couldn't make it work.

```csharp
@Ajax.ActionLink("Search", "ListCity", "Home", new { searchparameter = "inputfrominvestorinfo" }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "Citys" }, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "color:pink" })
```